# Correct workflow for backing up 2-4 TB of NAS data to external hard drive on monthly basis

Tags: backup, external-hard-drive, nas

I have a QNAP NAS server (with only one HDD slot) with a 4 TB drive installed. I would like to back up all data on monthly basis. What is the best workflow to do this?

1. I could simply copy all the files from the NAS to an external drive and either skip or overwrite the files, which could be pretty fast, but it wouldn't cover structure changes (e.g. if I moved the "Test" folder on the NAS in the meantime, it would end up duplicated on the external drive)
2. I could delete all files from external drive every month and copy everything from scratch - which would work perfectly but I am worried it'd be a pain. I think it would take much more time to complete, and also there would be an X-hour long window of non-existing backup.

Is there a way to manually and smartly mirror the NAS drive to an external drive?

Answer (score -1):

If most of the files do not change, you should use a copy-if-changed product.

Under Windows, you could use
[robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy).

A sample command would be:

```
robocopy source-path target-path  /mir /z
```

`/mir` : Mirrors a directory tree
`/z` : Copies files in restartable mode.

Otherwise, there are many third-party backup products that you could use.

Comment: Why the downvote? It would be nice to explain.